# When there are too many events on the timeline some are not shown

Tags: javascript, timeline, simile

I am using the Simile Timeline, and I am having a problem with events not "wrapping vertically".  When there are too many events around the same time the bottom events ones are not displayed.  Below, there are two large groups of events.  The first group on Jan 31 and the second on Feb 2, but each group contains more events than are shown.

[image: The overflow of events causes some of be hidden behind the lower scroll bar]

Is there a way to make the events "wrap" so that all events are shown?  (These elements do not share exactly the same time stamp, some are different by a few seconds)

Thanks,

Jordan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the autoWidth attribute, which is part of the Timeline ThemeClass

> autowidth : Should the Timeline automatically grow itself, as needed
>   when too many events for the available width are painted on the
>   visible part of the Timeline

More info here http://simile-widgets.org/wiki/Timeline_ThemeClass#autoWidthAnimationTime

Comment: I would, but my Theme Class seems to be missing the autoWidth property.  It looks like this:
_Timeline.ClassicTheme._Impl {firstDayOfWeek: 0, ether: Object, event: Object}_

Any ideas why that might be?

Comment: I just checked the source code and that property is no present: http://simile.mit.edu/timeline/api/scripts/themes.js

Comment: Have you tried using it though?

Check out this example : http://www.simile-widgets.org/timeline/examples/test_example2/test_example2.html

view the page source.


Also some of the documentation is outdated on their website

Comment: I must have been using an outdated source code or something, thanks!